# logstash grok pattern to parse mysql queries

Tags: mysql, regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I have mysql slowlogs in logstash and I'm wondering if anyone has had any luck parsing the query section to try and categorize statements. I'm stuck right now trying to split up the query by words in capital letters. I'm thinking that I can at least separate the initial statement. The specific question is this: how can I filter a message like this one so that I can at least deal with each section of the query split by words in capital letters?

So this:

```
SELECT column_one, column_two, COUNT(DISTINCT IF(column_three > 0, CONCAT('m_', column_three), CONCAT('r_', column_one))) AS tally FROM column_four WHERE ...
```

would parse into this:

```
field1: SELECT column_one, column_two, 
field2: COUNT(DISTINCT IF(column_three > 0,
field3: CONCAT('m_', column_three), 
field4:  AS tally 
... etc
```

Or something similar that would allow me to further clean the query and make it indexable.

Comment: You could use the lexer that mysql uses [sql_lex.cc](https://github.com/twitter/mysql/blob/master/sql/sql_lex.cc)

Comment: If you have arbitrary sql, do not rely on regex, really, use some parser.

Answer (score 0):

as replied by Wiktor. You should not rely on regex for such sql queries. But if there is some fixed pattern repeated every time, grok based parsing can be done. 
for your sample statement, say if the statement starts with `SELECT` and there are 2 `CONCAT` Followed by `AS` it can be parsed with following grok pattern:

```
(?<field_1>.+) (?<field_2>COUNT.+)(?<field_3>CONCAT.+)(?<field_4>CONCAT.+)(?<field_5>AS.+)
```

The parsed result will match the one you are looking for-

```
    {
      "field_1": [
        [
          "SELECT column_one, column_two,"
        ]
      ],
      "field_2": [
        [
          "COUNT(DISTINCT IF(column_three > 0, "
        ]
      ],
      "field_3": [
        [
          "CONCAT('m_', column_three), "
        ]
      ],
      "field_4": [
        [
          "CONCAT('r_', column_one))) "
        ]
      ],
      "field_5": [
        [
          "AS tally FROM column_four WHERE ..."
        ]
      ]
    }
```